# Wifi direct group reformation

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to create a file syncing app with wifi-direct. The issue I am facing is what happens if the group owner moves out of reach or suddenly disconnects, do the rest of the peers in the group re-form another group automatically ?
If somehow they form another group and the previous group owner comes in range, can he be automatically connected to the group or a manual intervention is needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such automated features. What happens is simply that all clients gets disconnected, and then your logic should kick in and start forming the group again.